# Spring boot oracle database without hibernate?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

i managed to connect my spring boot application with postgres without hibernate, but with r2dbc for a reactive application.

I was wondering if i can connect spring boot to oracle database without hibernate for a non reactive application ?

Comment: yes! first is Hibernate only one JPA-Provider between others, and secnod you can use spring jdbc and have no JPA at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data provides two basic modules for integrating applications with relational databases. [Spring Data JDBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc) is for imperative applications while [Spring Data R2DBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc) is for reactive ones. They both use the same interfaces and patterns. If you're familiar with Spring Data R2DBC, it will be straightforward to work with Spring Data JDBC.